# Use HTTPURLResponse in place of URLResponse

Tags: http, swift3

I want to call an API and its a part of my app, but I want to make sure I get the status code of the site I am calling into (to prevent runtime errors). I can't get the status code for URLResponse, but I can get it for HTTPURLResponse. How do I use the latter in place of the former?

```
    let requestURLString = "my_http_url"
    let requestURL = URL(string: requestURLString)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let ETAreq = session.dataTask(with: requestURL!)
    {

        (data, response (this is the URLResponse), error) in

        if error == nil
        {

            //switch (this is where I will put switch of status code)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though, `URLResponse` and `HTTPURLResponse` are renamed with losing `NS`-prefix. They still are classes and `HTTPURLResponse` is a subclass of `URLResponse`.

[HTTPURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpurlresponse)

You can use `as?` or `as!`:

```
    if
        error == nil,
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    {
        switch httpResponse.statusCode {
        case 200:
            //...
            break
        //...
        default:
            break
        }
    } else {
        //error case here...
    }
```

Comment: Based on what eskimo said here, is it safe to downcast as long as the URL in the request has an HTTP scheme.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120099